# What is the relationship called between a word and something/someone that does/performs that word?

Tags: single-word-requests

Basically, is there a word that relates "carpenter" to "carpentry" or "astronomer" to "astronomy"?

So if there is a subject that does some noun, is there a word or phrase for that relationship?

EDIT 1:

Sample sentence: "'activist' is a _________ of 'activism'." or "'architect' is a _________ of 'architecture'."

Comment: You mean a noun like trade, occupation or profession ?

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence with blanks where the word will be used.

Comment: @Centaurus added!

Comment: _Practicioner_. Proponent has a propaganda sense. Whereas simply practicing a profession is neutral.

Comment: The term is 'agent noun'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**practitioner**
noun [ C ]   formal
UK  /prækˈtɪʃ.ən.ər/ US  /prækˈtɪʃ.ən.ɚ/

**someone involved in a skilled job or activity:**

"'activist' is a **practitioner** of 'activism'.

"'architect' is a **practitioner** of 'architecture'."

Answer (score 0):

Proponent

A proponent is 'one who does something'. Or it can be 'one who promotes something - propels it forward.

- A carpenter is a proponent of carpentry
- An architect is a proponent of architecture
- An activist is a proponent of activism

From the Latin proponere 'to put forward'
https://www.etymonline.com/word/proponent

The word is usually described in dictionaries as someone who 'puts forward an argument' but it means more than that - it can mean to 'push forward' an industry, activity, way of being, thought, or art form - which is often done through action, and activity, not merely by talking.

If you want to 'be a proponent of eco architecture' for example, you could simply be talking about it, but another way of being a proponent would be to actually build an eco village that people can visit.

- Dickens - was a proponent of social reform (through his books)
- Madonna - is a proponent of women's sexual freedom (through her mode of dress, behaviour and way of being etc)
- Starbucks - is a proponent of great coffee